# Error in generated pdf file using zend_pdf under Magento

Tags: php, magento, zend-framework

I'm trying to create a PDF file, under a Magento phtml file, this is my code :

```
$pdf = new Zend_Pdf();


$pdf->pages[] = $pdf->newPage(Zend_Pdf_Page::SIZE_A4);

$page=$pdf->pages[0]; // this will get reference to the first page.

$style = new Zend_Pdf_Style();
$style->setLineColor(new Zend_Pdf_Color_Rgb(0,0,0));

$font = Zend_Pdf_Font::fontWithName(Zend_Pdf_Font::FONT_TIMES);

$style->setFont($font,12);

$page->setStyle($style);

$page->drawText('example text here',100,($page->getHeight()-100));
$pdf->render();

$pdf->save('test.pdf','true');
```

My PDF file is created, but I can't open it with acrobat reader.

When I open it with a text editor and compare it with another simple pdf files, I noticed that in the first line was missing in my generated pdf file. it contains `"%PDF-1.4"`

How can I add this line programmatically with zend_pdf in my pdf file ?

Thanks for help.

Comment: Reconsider going for the whhtmltopdf option! You will struggle building your own and getting sensible layout, if you use html as your render engine and then pop it into a peedo-file with wkhtmltopdf then you will spare yourself this misery! A few tricks in the approach, your can instruct Magento to render a different template if remote host equals local host and therefore get your html as you want it for the peedo-file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [zend manual](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.pdf.save.html) the second save parameter is only for updating files that already exist. In this case you are creating a new file so don't use that option.

```
$pdf->save('test.pdf');
```

---

<sub>PS. This answer is technically an [RTM](http://www.readthefuckingmanual.com/) statement.</sub>

Comment: Thank you and sorry for my bad question :)