# Creating cumulative pdf of orders in magento

Tags: magento-1.7, magento

I want to create a pdf of first 300 orders in magento. I want a functionality in which i will get first 300 orders and print their images(each order has different image) in a pdf. So how can i implement this functionality in magento. Is there any extension for that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look at /app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Sales/OrderController.php

```
public function pdfinvoicesAction(){
    $orderIds = $this->getRequest()->getPost('order_ids');
    $flag = false;
    if (!empty($orderIds)) {
        foreach ($orderIds as $orderId) {
            $invoices = Mage::getResourceModel('sales/order_invoice_collection')
                ->setOrderFilter($orderId)
                ->load();
            if ($invoices->getSize() > 0) {
                $flag = true;
                if (!isset($pdf)){
                    $pdf = Mage::getModel('sales/order_pdf_invoice')->getPdf($invoices);
                } else {
                    $pages = Mage::getModel('sales/order_pdf_invoice')->getPdf($invoices);
                    $pdf->pages = array_merge ($pdf->pages, $pages->pages);
                }
            }
        }
        if ($flag) {
            return $this->_prepareDownloadResponse(
                'invoice'.Mage::getSingleton('core/date')->date('Y-m-d_H-i-s').'.pdf', $pdf->render(),
                'application/pdf'
            );
        } else {
            $this->_getSession()->addError($this->__('There are no printable documents related to selected orders.'));
            $this->_redirect('*/*/');
        }
    }
    $this->_redirect('*/*/');
}
```

From the above function you could assign the first 300 order ids to $orderIds (or modify Mage::getResourceModel('sales/order_invoice_collection to get the first 300 records)

See [magento orders list query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5135283/magento-orders-list-query)

Changes :

```
public function pdfinvoicesAction(){
    $orderIds = $this->getRequest()->getPost('order_ids');
```

To (something like)

```
public function pdfinvoices($orderIds){
    $orderIds = (array) $orderIds;  // first 300 record ids
```

Change line to save pdf to file

```
 return $this->_prepareDownloadResponse(
            'invoice'.Mage::getSingleton('core/date')->date('Y-m-d_H-i-s').'.pdf', $pdf->render(),
            'application/pdf'
 );
```

To

```
 $pdf->render();
 // use the order_id for the pdf name like
 $pdf->save("{$orderId}.pdf");
```

see [Error in generated pdf file using zend_pdf under Magento](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8601232/error-in-generated-pdf-file-using-zend-pdf-under-magento)

You could also delete the $this->_redirect('*/*/')

Comment: How to print the pdf with the data from above? In an external script?